# Trigger a function with jQuery after a single letter was typed in an input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to make a simple search box. How can I trigger a function just after a single letter was typed in an input box? I used .keyup, but this seems to be useless, because when a diacritic character is typed, the function is triggered three times.

```
<input id="text" type="text" />
<div></div>
<script>
    $('#text').keyup(function(){
        $('div').append('TEST'+$(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

The above code works fine unless you type any diacritic character: ą, ś, ł, ż, ź, ć, etc.

I can't use .keypress or .keydown since they trigger a function before a character is typed.

EDITED LATER:

I know that my example might not be clear enough to understand the problem, but... In my real code every time a letter is typed, an SQLite query is executed. If a type a diacritic character or a capital letter, the query is executed three or two times, which slows down the whole script. It won't make a big difference if you execute the script in a computer web browser, but there is significant lag in mobile browsers.

Comment: just prevent doing anything on shift-ctrl-alt and should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I considered checking the value of the string compared to the last time it was changed. So keypresses don't run the function unless it causes the string to be changed.

http://jsfiddle.net/82sTJ/1/

Comment: Both yours and user1078510's answers solve my problem. But your solution works without editing, so I decided to mark your answer as "accepted". Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 5):

```
var i = 0;    

$('#text').keyup(function(event) {
    i++;
    if(i == 1)
    {
        $('div').append('TEST'+$(this).val());
    }
});
```

This to me should work, you could also detect the specific key being entered

Comment: You were really close! I added a bit more of code and it works perfectly! Your code just needs: .keydown(function(event){i=0;});